# 'pipx install gvsbuild' successful but won't then run 'gvsbuild build gtk3' in powershell

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pipx

I am following the steps on the github page and [am at this step](https://github.com/wingtk/gvsbuild#build-gtk).

[A search for 'gvsbuild' on my system.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saBSp.png)

[Windows PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTkaF.png)

tried:
"gvsbuild build gtk3"
expecting gtk3 to be built.
result:

```
gvsbuild : The term 'gvsbuild' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ gvsbuild build gtk3
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gvsbuild:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to keep everything related to the question self-contained here. Content on 3rd party sites is subject to change at any time, and the last thing future users want is to see a broken link.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like pipx isn't on your path, so when you install a command like gvsbuild, PowerShell can't find it.

When installing pipx, you need to restart your PowerShell after you run `pipx ensurepath`.

The ensurepath command adds both \AppData\Roaming\Python\Python3x\Scripts and %USERPROFILE%.local\bin folder to your search path. However, those changes might not be made until you restart your shell.